# can i change my iOS deployment target to 5.0 on xcode 4.5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, xcode4.5

I developed iPhone app using `base SDKs` as 6.0 and `deployment target` as 6.0

Now i want to change my `deployment target` to 5.0 instead of 6.0

is it possible to change ?

I have used feature of autolayout in xcode 4.5

and

**I have one doubt:** I have heard that if i develop app using deployment target of iOS 5 and with launch image of `Default-568h@2x.png` for iPhone 5 apple will reject my app..(**Reason : Invalid Launch Image - You app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later**) but for support of iPhone 5, i have to supply image `Default-568h@2x.png` image. how to solve this problem ?

***Thanks for the reading of question.***

Comment: Why not just supply `Default-568h@2x.png` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to change the base SDK to change the deployment target. Just change it to 5.0 under your target options:

[image]

Note that autolayout and some other features are available only on SDK 6.0.

**Edit for XCode 7+**

The tab is now called *General*, and the *Deployment target* is under *Deployment info*:

[image: XCode 7]

Comment: I need to do separate  coding for iOS 5 and 6 ?

Comment: No, whatever you do for iOS 5 will work on iOS 6 as well. Only if you used some mechanisms added in iOS 6, you need to replace them with something else to make it work on iOS 5.

Comment: In Xcode 7, this option is under **General** settings of the project.

Answer (score 1):

You might also notice that you can't see older deployment targets from Adis way. So to fix that go to `build settings>deployment` and then locate `iOS deployment target` and change it there.

[image: picture what's described above]