# -[UIBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, uibarbuttonitem

I have developed one application with **deployment target** and **ios sdk  as 6.0**. Later my client demanded the app should run in ios 5.0+ devices.So i have changed deployment target to 5.0 and disabled autolayout property of IB as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14772122/2086830) in stack, but now iam getting the error as shown below:

> **> -[UIBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2971f0**

And i didn't find anything wrong with my UIBarButtonItem,

```
 addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
        target:self
        action:@selector(addProject)];
```

now iam struggling to find a solution, waiting for your valuable help..
thanks in advance.

Comment: That method is only available in iOS 6.0+

Comment: i haven't used any method like that..
this is what i have in my code:- 
addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
    target:self
    action:@selector(addProject)];

Comment: Its Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: @ElliottPerry you should write that as an answer because it's correct. He needs to do respondstoselector and have the two versions of the add button.

Comment: Should make a custom button and add it to bar button using initWithCustomView

Comment: @mvp You're correct, there should be nothing wrong with that line of code. The problem must be elsewhere. Could you humor me and search your codebase for the `setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:` method (obviously don't search for that entire line of text because it will be broken up by parameter names and types. **Try searching for "barMetrics"**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` is available in iOS 5.0+ but `setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:` is only available in iOS 6.0+

Comment: `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` is available in iOS **5.0+** but `setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:` is only available in iOS **6.0+**.

Comment: do an if responds to selector to pick which one, not based on the OS version. that's the right way to know which one to use.