# Full screen IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, display

I just started on Xcode, and i have a little problem
I would like to display the application on the entire screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyXJ1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add launch images in your code for ios devices:

Here is the detail description about it:

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

Comment: I Agree with Shehzad:  Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671868/app-not-using-full-height-of-iphone-5 - it seems like the phone uses the startup images to determine the resolutions supported by the app.  Adding images for the 5 and 6 screen sizes should make the phone realise you support the taller screen size.