# View does not spread over entire screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am taking a self-paced iOS course and doing a project. The sample code is written in swift and it is 2-year-old. I managed covert it to swift 3 but there is one problem left: the view does not spread over the entire screen. It only use 80% of the screen.

I suspect it is due to the code is originally designed for iPhone 5, and I am running it on iPhone 6s.

What I have checked:

1. reset constraints
2. reset frames
3. clean all warnings
4. on storyboard, there is only 1 table view with 4 constraints. Aspect Fill.

My question:
What else should I check?

Comment: Any screenshots & Constraints screenshot? Does the old code has this problem ?

Comment: Please provide screenshots.

Comment: You need to add launch screen, then it will automatically update for bigger size iphone

Answer (score 0):

Check your project has the correct LaunchImage in the image catalog set. This SO question might provide more context - [App not using full height of iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19671868)