# Full screen is not working on iPhone 5s with Ionic 3 on iOS 11

Tags: cordova, ionic3, ios11

We have a problem to enable full screen on iPhone 5s with iOS11.

We are developing this app with Ionic 3.15 and Cordova 7.0.1

[image]

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435646/1686932). It got me to my solution.

I had just updated to xcode 9.1 and IOS 11.11, and since the update, I was having these issues.

Solution: Go to project settings (first item in file manager) > General > App icons and launch images (roughly halfway down).

For me the 3rd dropdown "Launch Screen file" was empty. I selected CDVLauncherScreen.storyboard, and that fixed it.