# iPad listed under 'Ineligible Devices'(OS version)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8.2

Lat day i updated my iPad to iOS 8.2, now when i try to run my Xcode project, my iPad is listed under 'Ineligible Devices' in bracket its is written as (OS version). Why is it listed so? Won't my app be able to run in iOS8.2 devices?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/xcode6-ineligible-devices-section-appeared

Comment: Please Update your Xcode also. If it is 6.1 than it'll display as ineligible.

Comment: Please update your xcode to latest version because may be your xcode supports less than version of your device version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Deployement Target to lower value.[Change Deployement Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770834/can-i-change-my-ios-deployment-target-to-5-0-on-xcode-4-5/)

Comment: Whats ur current Deployment target ??

Comment: This worked for me with Xcode 6.3 and iPad mini on 8.2 except backwards. Had to change from 7.0 to 8.3, build, then put it back to 7.0. Strange.